# How to add custom error message when using createsuperuser command in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a custom user model and I want email and username to be a unique field. And I am using email as my main username field. Both are unique. The issue is that when I create a "createsuperuser" I get an instant error if the email is already taken by someone but in case of username field it checks the unique condition at the end which gives an ugly Postgres unique constraint failed error. I want username field to be instantly checked like the email field.

**Check the images below.**

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'full_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

[This is what I want image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2J4A.png)

[This is what I am getting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJUxs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own django command to create superuser. A sample create superuser command can be:

```py
# your_app/management/commands/create_custom_superuser.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if not get_user_model().objects.filter(username="admin").exists():
            # you can add some logs here
            get_user_model().objects.create_superuser("admin", "admin@admin.com", "admin")
```

Then you can create superuser by `python manage.py create_custom_superuser`.